# JSON.NET: getting json from external source with streams, how to get just one value?

Tags: json, c#-4.0, json.net

I have the following code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    using (Stream stream = client.GetStreamAsync("https://opendata.rdw.nl/resource/8ys7-d773.json?kenteken=61SFSL").Result)
    using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(stream))
    using (JsonReader reader = new JsonTextReader(streamReader))
    {
        JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();

        // read the json from a stream
        // json size doesn't matter because only a small piece is read at a time from the HTTP request


        //What do I do here to get my one value?


    }

    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
    Console.Read();
}
```

I got this from the documentation over at the JSON.NET website. The reason being that I don't want to load the whole string, but piece by piece. The response is as follows:

```
[{"brandstof_omschrijving":"Benzine","brandstof_volgnummer":"1","brandstofverbruik_buiten":"6.60","brandstofverbruik_gecombineerd":"8.20","brandstofverbruik_stad":"11.10","co2_uitstoot_gecombineerd":"196","emissiecode_omschrijving":"Euro 4","geluidsniveau_rijdend":"71","geluidsniveau_stationair":"82","kenteken":"61SFSL","milieuklasse_eg_goedkeuring_licht":"70/220*2001/100B","nettomaximumvermogen":"99.00","toerental_geluidsniveau":"4125"}]
```

I.e., it returns an array with one json object, and I want to retrieve just one value in there, using a stream. How might I do this?

Comment: You are creating a lot of problems for yourself. You will basically re-writing a parser.

Comment: Okay... So what are you suggesting?

Comment: any particular reason you cannot load the result? is it a rather large amount of data?

Comment: which value are your trying to access?

Comment: No, as far as I know, you cannot request an array of multiple objects. There's a sample in my question of how the data looks like. Silly enough, I only need one value. But to answer your quesion in short: no, it is not a lot of data.


In the string, I'm trying to get to the value with the key "co2_uitstoot_gecombineerd"

Comment: then you can use dynamic. and get the first item in the array and then the property you want.

Comment: And still use the streams? Or should I abandon that one?

Comment: I would say forget the stream. no need to over complicate things

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127388/discussion-between-garth-marenghi-and-nkosi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using Newtonsoft;

public class Program {

    public static void Main() {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var json = client.GetStringAsync("https://opendata.rdw.nl/resource/8ys7-d773.json?kenteken=61SFSL").Result;
        var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);
        string value = data[0].co2_uitstoot_gecombineerd;
        Console.WriteLine(value);
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```